# SQL command not executing as expected

Tags: c#, sql

What is wrong with this code? I want to catch the last value from SQL row and display it in a `TextBox`. Kindly help me.

```
private void textBox2_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cmd.Connection = cn;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = "select last(remain) from item_new_customer where cust=" + textBox2.Text + "";
    float h = (float)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    textBox20.Text = h.ToString();
}
```

Comment: What is the error you are receiving?

Comment: Your question doesn't really make sense. The title says `last` but your code sample says `max`. What issues are you seeing?

Comment: Maybe you need to enclose it in `single quotes like '` for textbox value, also look into parameterized queries

Comment: Please change your title..

Comment: DO NOT send data directly from the UI to the database. You are leaving yourself wide open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sql_injection)

Comment: This is a store control program, in it a form named customer bill, I want to catch a value from last customer's previous bill and display this value in textbox named textBox20.Text

Comment: What if the user enters `user42; drop table item_new_customer; go;` in the text box?

Answer (score 2):

```
cmd.CommandText = "select max(remain) from item_new_customer where cust='" + textBox2.Text + "'";
```

Comment: What if the user enters `'user42; drop table item_new_customer; go;` in the text box?

Answer (score 1):

You are open for SQL-Injection, use parameters to avoid it.

To answer your actual question, i assume that you want this column: `remain`. But you want the value of the last inserted record. Since you haven't mentioned the column to detect the order of insertion, i use the primary key column (not recommended):

```
string sql = "SELECT TOP 1 remain FROM dbo.tablename WHERE cust=@cust ORDER BY id DESC";
using(var con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using(var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con))
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cust", textBox2.Text);
    con.Open();
    double h = (double)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    textBox20.Text = h.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Why row_number instead of TOP 1 ... ORDER BY id DESC?

Comment: @ta.speot.is: There are more than one possible ways, you could also use a sub-query(`WHERE id=(SELECT MAX(Id)...`)

Comment: And row_number does not really express intent that well. I think you will find the execution plan is more expensive, too.

Comment: @ta.speot.is: Point taken :)

Comment: I have a new problem in this (float h = (float)cmd.ExecuteScalar();)

Comment: @ahmed: What type is it in the database?

Comment: it's type in SQLDatabase is float.Thanks (Tim Schmelter)

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a single quote after the `textBox2.Text`:

```
private void textBox2_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cmd.Connection = cn;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;


    cmd.CommandText = 
   "select max(remain) from item_new_customer where cust=" + textBox2.Text + "'";
                                                          //Missing tick here ^ 
    float h = (float)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    textBox20.Text = h.ToString();
}
```

In addition, your code is an open invitation for [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sql_injection).

Comment: SQL Injection is not limited to web applications.

Comment: this project is not a web project.

Comment: @ahmed, as ta.speot.is pointed out, it's not just web projects that are vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: My problem in (float h = (float)cmd.ExecuteScalar();)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks very much for all
My final right code is:

```
cmd.Connection = cn;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "select top 1(remain) from item_new_customer where cust='"+textBox2.Text+"' order by id desc";
        int h = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        textBox20.Text = h.ToString();
```

Comment: if the name typed into textBox2.Text is not exist in SQL table the program how can tell me this name is not exist in table?

Answer (score 0):

What I would just do is put all of the SQL row values into a listbox and then take the text of the last item in the textbox and put that into a textbox.  Keep the listbox hidden

```
    private System.Windows.Forms.ListBox listBox1;
    static SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=hostname;Initial Catalog=database_name;Integrated Security=False;User ID=user;Password=123456;");
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from table_name", connection);
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    adapter.Fill(table);
    foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
    {
    listBox1.Items.Add(row["row_name"].ToString());
    }
    textBox20.Text = listBox1.Items[listBox1.Items.Count - 1].ToString();
```